# In IE7 and IE6, setting element.style['display'] = 'inherit' thows an exception

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

What's a good workaround to this IE bug that would still allow me to set the display style of an HTML element to 'inherit' in IE7 or IE6 using javascript?

```
    var el = document.getElementById('someElementID');
    if (!el) return false;
    try {
        var displayValue = 'inherit';
        //the next line throws exception in IE7 and IE6
        // when displayValue = 'inherit'
        // but not for other legit values like 'none', 'block', 'inline' or even ''
        el.style['display'] = displayValue;
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
```

Assume that I *don't* want to set `visible: hidden`, `position:absolute` it out of view or `z-index` it under something else.

Comment: `display: inherit`? What do you need this for?

Comment: `display` is already "inherited" in a sense: if you set `display: none` on an element, all children are implicitly hidden.

Comment: ...which means that if you want the `display` property to be inherited, do this: `el.style.display = '';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of values for the `display` property was added in CSS 2, and `inherit` is one of them. Older browsers don't support these new values. You can compare the possible values in [CSS 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#display) and [CSS 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop).

Even if you could set the value, it's useless as the browser doesn't know what to do with it.

Comment: I don't mind the browser ignoring it as much as throwing an exception.
It turns out that of all the allowable CSS2 display properties, inherit is the only one that throws an exception in IE6&7.
OK, thanks for the help, folks!